# search list in where with and condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I has a table Project

```
id|title
___________________
1|water blue 
2|test water blue low test
3|low   blue
```

I has a list Search(Search list is dynamic and fill with user with any value and with any number row)

```
string[] search = new string[] { "water", "blue", "low" };
```

I want write this query with ef6

```
select * from project 
where title like '%water%' and title like'%blue%' and title like '%low%'
```

I write this code but this return all row (i want only row 2 water blue low)

```
 var result = (from p in context.project     
               where seartch.Contains(p.title)    
              select p     
               ).ToList();
```

Please help me

Comment: something like `values.All(value => source.Contains(value))` ? Or can we simply add a where clause for each of those value. with a loop ? I'm not sure the first one will work in EF. But the second is pretty common.

Comment: If you use the query syntax, you must end it in some projection (e.g., `select` or `group by` clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this
You will only get the row 2. As it take consideration of matching all records in your search string.

```
from p in context.project 
.Where(g => search.All(h => g.Title.Contains(h)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var result = search.Where(x=>x.Contains("water") || x.Contains("blue")).ToArray();
Array.ForEach(result, Console.WriteLine);
```

**UPDATE**

```
var result =  context.project.Where(x=>Array.IndexOf(search, x.Title) > -1);
```

Comment: search list is dynamic and fill with user with any value

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way

```
var query = from p in context.project;
foreach(var item in search)
    query.Where(p => p.Title.Contains(item));

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: search list is dynamic and fill with user with any value

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @ashkufaraz

Answer (score 0):

By SQL-like query

```
 var result = (from p in context.project     
               where (p.title.Contains(search[0])&  p.title.Contains(search[1])&p.title.Contains(search[2])                         
               ).ToList();
```

By lambda exp

```
var result= context.project.Where(p=>p.title.Contains(search[0])&p.title.Contains(search[1])&p.title.Contains(search[2])).ToList();
```

Comment: search list is dynamic and fill with user with any value

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is the wrong way around. The equivalent SQL would be

```
WHERE title IN ('water', 'blue', 'low')
```

The correct query can be built by iterating over the array of search terms, and create a where term for each. The terms are implicitly AND'ed by linq:

```
IQueryable<Project> query = context.project;
foreach (var s in search) {
  query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(s));
}

var result = query.ToList();
```